# Why am I not able to load ggplot2 in Rstudio?

Tags: r, installation, package

I have installed R and RStudio but I believe I have set the environment variables correctly. I have installed ggplot2 along with its dependencies but I am unable to load ggplot2 even after running RStudio as admin. Here are some glimpses:

```
    > install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
      Installing package into ‘C:/Users/mosen/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
      (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
```

Then I get to see the notifications of the dependent packages getting installed from various CRAN urls and then the unpacking of those packages....

```
       package ‘knitr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
       package ‘rmarkdown’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
       package ‘svglite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
       package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

etc. Then after certain verification I get the message,

```
        The downloaded source packages are in
       ‘C:\Users\mosen\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCOIHuQ\downloaded_packages’
```

I could see the zipped files in this directory. However,

```
         > load("ggplot2")
           Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the 
           connection
           In addition: Warning message:
           In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
           cannot open compressed file 'ggplot2', probable reason 'No such 
           file or directory'
```

Please help! My working directory is "C:/Users/mosen/Documents".

Comment: "I believe I have set the environment variables correctly" -- Which are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need `library(ggplot2)` or `require(ggplot2)` instead of `load(ggplot2)` after `install.packages("ggplot2")`. `Load("...")` is a function to load datasets, not to enable using functions from packages.